# Excel VBA - Add submenu to custom right-click menu

Tags: excel, vba

Long time viewer, first time poster.
I have a form with Right-Click functions that work fine.
I'm trying to add a sub menu to the main right-click menu to separate some functions/command.  I need/want to insert the section where the 'Select Case' is, however, its only showing the top menu.
Not sure where to go from here.  Any help would be awesome

Thanks :)

P.S. I would be happy to explain further if needed.

```
Sub fzCopyPaste(iItems As Integer)
On Error Resume Next
CommandBars("Custom").Delete
Set PopBar = CommandBars.Add(Name:="Custom", Position:=msoBarPopup, MenuBar:=False, Temporary:=True)
```

'Add top_menu on Main Popbar : This work fine

```
Set top_menu = PopBar.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
With top_menu
    '.FaceId =
    .Caption = "&Some Commands"
End With
```

Need to Insert the below sub menu(s) into the top menu
But nothing shows up : Does not work

```
Select Case iItems
Case 1  ' Copy and Paste
    Set copy_button = top_menu.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
    With copy_button
        .FaceId = 19
        .Caption = "&Copy"
        .Tag = "tCopy"
        .OnAction = "fzCopyOne(true)"
    End With

    Set paste_button = top_menu.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
    With paste_button
        .FaceId = 22
        .Tag = "tPaste"
        .Caption = "&Paste"
        .OnAction = "fzCopyOne(true)"
    End With
Case 2 '  Paste Only
    Set paste_button = top_menu.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
    With paste_button
        .FaceId = 22
        .Tag = "tPaste"
        .Caption = "&Paste"
        .OnAction = "fzCopyOne(true)"
    End With
End Select
```

'Extra top menue(s) below here : This work fine

```
    Set paste_button = PopBar.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
    With paste_button
        .FaceId = 22
        .Tag = "tPaste"
        .Caption = "Main POP BAR 2"
        .OnAction = "fzCopyOne(true)"
    End With


PopBar.ShowPopup

CommandBars("Custom").Delete
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You set `Copy_Button` equal to an `msoControlButton`. If you want a button, this is correct. You want a menu though, so you should set it to an `msoControlPopup`. Try something like this:

```
Set Top_Menu = PopBar.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlPopup)
With Top_Menu 
    .Caption = "&Some Commands"
    Set MySubMenu = .Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlPopup, before:=1, temporary:=True)
    Select Case iItems
        Case 1
            With MySubMenu
                .Caption = "Submenu Commands"
                With .Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton, before:=1, temporary:=True)
                    .FaceId = 19
                    .Caption = "&Copy"
                    .Tag = "tCopy"
                    .OnAction = "fzCopyOne(true)"
                End With

                With .Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton, before:=2, temporary:=True)
                    .FaceId = 22
                    .Tag = "tPaste"
                    .Caption = "&Paste"
                    .OnAction = "fzCopyOne(true)"
                End With
            End With
        Case 2
            'etc
    End Select
End With
```

I removed the “Top_Menu” section (first 3 lines) with the below; it was adding an extra button and then the desired menu.

```
Set MySubMenu = PopBar.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlPopup, before:=1, temporary:=True)
With MySubMenu
    .Caption = "&Some Commands"
```

Comment: Thanks @Tim for explaining that, works great.  I made an edit though, but works great non-the-less.