# How to add Sub Menu under Sub Menu in VBA Excel?

Tags: vba, excel

```
        Set subMenu = menutext.Controls.add(Type:=msoControlButton, ID:=3, before:=2)
        With subMenu
            .Caption = "MainMenu"
            .Enabled = True
        End With

       Set subMenu = menutext.Controls.add(Type:=msoControlButton, ID:=3, before:=k + 1)
       With subMenu
            .Caption = "SubMenu"
            .Enabled = True
        End With
```

I want (Is it Possible??)- 
 MainMenu -->SubMenu -->SubsubMenu.
Till I was able to get MainMenu --> SubMenu.

Comment: A bit of context please... Is this in a userform or in the Excel GUI itself? And if the latter, what version of Excel are you using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel VBA - Add submenu to custom right-click menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38377618/excel-vba-add-submenu-to-custom-right-click-menu)

Comment: @RikSportel It is in Excel GUI and 2010

Comment: Have a look at the custom UI editor on [Ron de Bruin his website](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/section2.htm) - Everything you could possibly want to know related to editing the ribbon is there, including some tools to easily create all the menu's you want.

Comment: @RikSportel thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Set menutext = Application.CommandBars("Cell").Controls.Add(msoControlPopup)
    With menutext
        .Caption = "MainMenu"
        .Enabled = True
    End With

   Set subMenu = menutext.Controls.Add(msoControlPopup)
   With subMenu
        .Caption = "SubMenu"
        .Enabled = True
    End With

   Set subMenuSubMenu = subMenu.Controls.add(Type:=msoControlButton, ID:=3, before:=k + 1)
   With subMenuSubMenu
        .Caption = "SubMenuSubMenu"
        .Enabled = True
    End With
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.